# test functions and the value of $\delta'$ at 0

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

First of all, I apologize if this question has been asked before, I searched the site using relevant search terms and couldn't find anything that directly answered my question.

A good example of a test function is the so called "bump function" which I'm defining as

$\varphi = 
\begin{cases} 
c\exp\left(\frac{-\epsilon^{2}}{\epsilon^{2}-(x-a)^{2}}\right) & \text{if $|x-a|<\epsilon$} \\
0 & \text{if $|x-a|\ge \epsilon$}
\end{cases}
$

where $c>0$, $d>0$, $a\in \mathbb{R}$.

This function should meet both requirements to be a test function, namely that it has compact support and that it is smooth (obviously correct me if I'm wrong).

As far as I can tell, supp($\varphi$)$=[a-d,a+d]$.

According to wikipedia,

$\langle \delta',\varphi\rangle = -\varphi'(0)$

Most depictions of $\delta'$ show that it 'equals' 0 at 0, yet I can just choose $\epsilon=2$, $a=1$, and $c=4$, and clearly $-\varphi'\ne0$. I understand that $\delta'$ is a distribution and not a function, so these representations are just to get an idea of what $\delta'$, but I still seem to be missing something.

Do we have to take $\lim\limits_{\epsilon,a\to 0}\varphi$? Even if we can show this, this is obviously only a small subset of all test functions, is there a way to generalize this claim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\langle \delta',\varphi\rangle = -\varphi'(0)$ is the definition of the distribution $\delta'$, the other one is $\langle \delta',\varphi\rangle=\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_{-\infty}^\infty (n e^{-\pi x^2 n^2})' \varphi(x)dx$. The idea that $\delta'$ equals something at $0$ is wrong, it is the limit -in the sense of distributions- of two peaks getting closer, as in $f'(0)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(h)-f(-h)}{2h}$

As a distribution on $\Bbb{R}-\{0\}$ we have $\delta'=0$, so it can be identified to the zero function away from $0$.

Comment: Are there any texts you'd recommend on the topic?

Comment: Ok, I think I might be understanding more, so this distribution maps from the set of test functions to some real valued number that is defined by $-\varphi(0)$, right? The fact that it maps from the set of test functions is what makes it wrong to say that it "equals" something at zero, am I still on the right track? So following from this, for all points lying on the y axis, can we find at least one $\varphi$ that $\delta'$ maps to?  Thanks for your help! I really appreciate it. (Also sorry for double commenting; I unintentionally spent too long considering an edit).

Comment: Your approach is correct, the other one (called "limit in the sense of distributions") is that it is the limit of a sequence of functions where the limit is said to converge by making the sequence of functions act (through $\int$) on test functions. Because we require that the map you mentioned is continuous (in the test function topology...) both approach are the same. The distributional derivative is just the usual derivative applied to the sequence of functions

Comment: (that's why I obtained $$\langle \delta,\varphi\rangle=\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_{-\infty}^\infty n e^{-\pi x^2 n^2} \varphi(x)dx=\varphi(0),\qquad \langle \delta',\varphi\rangle=\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_{-\infty}^\infty (n e^{-\pi x^2 n^2})' \varphi(x)dx=-\varphi'(0)$$